# PHP не создается выпадающий список из json-строки

Tags: php, json

Не создается выпадающий список. Где ошибка?

```
<?php
$t = '<select name="time">';
foreach($obj2['Intervals'][$b] as $d)
{
    $t = '<option value="'.$d['StartTime'].'"></option>';
}
$t = '</select>';
echo $t;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли выставить оператор присваивания с конкатенацией `.=`
Из-за чего переменная ваша не дополнялась, а перезаписывалась.

```
<?php
$t = '<select name="time">';
foreach($obj2['Intervals'][$b] as $d)
{
    $t .= '<option value="'.$d['StartTime'].'"></option>';
}
$t .= '</select>';
echo $t;
?>
```